# why torque motor doesn't overheat if stalled for very long?

Tags: motor

why torque motor does not overheat if stalled for very long,
could some explain how. If used in servo mechanisms where cooling(nature or forced) in nearly impractical.

Answer (score 3):

A torque motor is designed to be run at stall. Maintaining torque at a fixed shaft position is exactly how you expect it to be run.

The motor is designed so that its thermal characteristics allow this operation. The windings are relatively thick, so the Joule heating is minimized, and the case construction allows good transfer of internal heat to the surrounding structure. The windings are normally located far from the shaft axis, so that the product of magnetic force and radius of action (torque) is maximized. This in turn means that the windings are well-coupled thermally to the case, and there is relatively little heat dissipated deep within the motor.

Comment: And for torque control a current limit is set so that the motor is not stalled on a constant voltage supply?

Comment: @Transistor - Depends on the system. As an example, http://www.machinedesign.com/motorsdrives/torque-motors-do-trick notes, "Heat produced by the motor must be removed by a cooling system to avoid overheating machine elements." So, if the user limits heat transfer, then current limiting would be necessary, although this would be difficult to determine open-loop. A current limit triggered by motor temperature would be preferred. If the cooling is up to scratch, no current limit.